# How can I run different actions from one view in django pushing two different buttons at HTML page

Tags: python, django

I have html page with 2 buttons. I want open one bootstrap modal window were I can load photo cliking at "Photo" button and another bootstrap window for load video cliking at "Video" button. I was looking in google but I didn't find solutions.

I tried to use in wiew.py this code "if 'photo' in request.POST: do somthing", and "if request.POST.get('Photo') == 'Photo': do somthing"

view.py

```py
def make_post(request):

    if request.POST.get('Photo') == 'Photo':
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = InstagramPhotoForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('success_send')
        else:
            form = InstagramPhotoForm()
        return render(request, 'createinstagrampost/createinstagrampost.html', {'photoform' : form})
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = InstagraVideoForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('success_send')
        else:
            form = InstagramVideoForm()
        return render(request, 'createinstagrampost/createinstagrampost.html', {'videoform': form})
```

createinstagrampost.html

```
<form>
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div>
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-1" name="photo" value="Photo"></button>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-2" name="video" value="Video"></button>
  </div>
  <br>
</form>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class='modal-title'>Make photo post</h4>
        <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <fieldset class="form-group">
            {{ photoform|crispy }}
          </fieldset>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Update</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal-2">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class='modal-title'>Make video post</h4>
        <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <fieldset class="form-group">
            {{ videoform|crispy }}
          </fieldset>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Update</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('profile/createinstagrampost/', instagram_post.make_post, name='createinstagrampost'),
    path('profile/success/', instagram_post.success_send, name = 'success_send'),
    ...
]
```

I found that when I asked if "POST request" constain button "name" it return nothing.

Anyone could give me a hand with that ? That would be really helpful.

Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 0):

as marciks mentioned first you need add `method=POST` to  `<form>` to send request as Post and add `type='submit'` to button belong to  :

```
<post method='POST' >
    <button type='submit' ... >
    . 
</form>
```

then your button name is 'photo' with lower-case character not 'Photo'. so try :

```
def make_post(request):

    if request.POST.get('photo') == 'Photo':
       . 
       . 
       . 
   else:
       . 
       .
```

Comment: No effect. Still the same.

Comment: With submit button it's just reload the page when I click on it. When I changed type to `button` it open video form and I can see the form but when I click on photo button it's show me just modal window without form inside.

Answer (score 0):

Your view is a little bit confuse.. When you enter an url in the browser, it will make a GET request for that url, so you want to 'read' this get request first:

```
if request.POST.get('Photo') == 'Photo':
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = InstagramPhotoForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('success_send')
        return render(request, 'createinstagrampost/createinstagrampost.html', {'photoform' : form})
```

Since the first request is a GET, it will skip the first if and return the template. Then in the forms, when user post something to this same view, it will be a 'POST' request.. This time, the code in the first if will run and your form will be saved